# Setting folder permission on a remote Windows 2008 R2 server in PowerShell or Command Prompt

Tags: windows, permissions, remote, directory

Does anyone know of a way to set a folder's permissions on a remote server using either PowerShell or the command prompt?

In other words, sitting at `server01`, launch PS or CP, type a command to set `\\\server02\c$\folder` to read only for `user01` and full control for `user02`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `set-acl` if you'd like to use PowerShell for this task.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  for anyone else wondering, this worked for me...

$acl = get-acl -path “\\server02\sharedFolder”

$new = “DOMAIN\user”,”FullControl”,”ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit”,”None”,”Allow”

$accessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $new

$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)

$acl | Set-Acl “\\server02\sharedFolder”